# plot time series data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, time-series

I have a `data frame`

```
                       BA   HRS   SPR    TGI
11/21/2006 00:00:00 91.10 43.55 29.00 25.925
11/22/2006 00:00:00 90.10 44.57 29.35 26.025
11/24/2006 00:00:00 89.77 44.02 28.80 25.880
11/27/2006 00:00:00 87.37 42.46 28.39 25.800
11/28/2006 00:00:00 87.94 41.91 28.31 25.970
11/29/2006 00:00:00 88.89 42.40 29.02 26.455
```

I would like to plot the time series with `ggplot`, all together, having the dates row names as the x axis.

I am very new to `R` and I would appreciate some boilerplate code to start experimenting with the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make times the first column of your data frame (df) and call the column "time".

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") 
df.m <- melt(df, id.vars = "time")
ggplot(df.m) + geom_line(aes(x = time, y = value, colour = variable))
```

*Cookbook for R* is great.